# How to add timestamp on MySQL outputfile?

Tags: mysql, excel

I'm making an event that runs every minute and extracts certain columns on a table and creates an output-file in excel format

Since I cannot overwrite the file, i wanted to append a time-stamp on the filename so it will create unique excel filenames.

Here is the sample of my event

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS 'Extract_Users'

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Minute

COMMENT 'Data Extraction' DO SELECT userID, email, id FROM table_one.user_name

INTO OUTFILE 'C:\path\path\Desktop\test\user.xls'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with the help of prepare statement, you can achieve it. not tested but i think worth to give shot.

```
   DELIMITER $$
    CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS 'Extract_Users'
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Minute 
    COMMENT 'Data Extraction'  
    DO 
    BEGIN
    SET @sql_text = CONCAT("SELECT userID, email, id FROM table_one.user_name INTO OUTFILE INTO OUTFILE 'C:\path\path\Desktop\test\'" , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d') , "user.xls'" ); 
    PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text; 
    EXECUTE s1; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this will help.

~K

Comment: Hello Metalfight, I tried your revisions on the script but it didn't word. I also removed the double INTO OUTFILE but it doesnt work.

Comment: Im not sure what is wrong, but it's not sending the output in the folder I specified

DELIMITER $$
    CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `Extract_Users`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Minute 
    COMMENT 'Extract_Users'  
    DO
    BEGIN
    SELECT @sql_stmt = CONCAT("SELECT userID, email, id FROM user_tabe.user_info INTO OUTFILE 'C:\path\path\Desktop\test\Log-",DATE_FORMAT( NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %T'),"'.xls");
    PREPARE extrct FROM @sql_stmt;
    EXECUTE extrct;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to metalfight for giving me idea on how to approach the event.

Here is the answer to my question. This works.

> DELIMITER $$
>
> CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `Extract_Users`
>
> ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Minute COMMENT 'Extract_Users'
>
> DO
>
> BEGIN
>
> SET @sql_stmt := concat("SELECT userID, email, id FROM user_table.user_info INTO OUTFILE C:/path/path/desktop/test/Users-",DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d_%H%i%s'),".xls'");
>
> PREPARE extrct FROM @sql_stmt;
>
> EXECUTE extrct;
>
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE extrct;
>
> END $$
>
> DELIMITER ;